# Is that a sundew?

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image]

I have bought the seeds for a sundew/drosera (growbro.nl) but I have pretty serious doubt if that is really the plant I wanted :-)

If not, what kind of plant is that I have grown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a sundew. A simple Google search can confirm that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I still hoped that it is maybe just a transition phase and it will look as the actual sundew.

Answer (score 0):

That looks a bit like a member of the genus *Impatiens* some members of which are invasive.

Some images can be [seen here](https://garden.org/plants/photo/193106/).

Flower pictures would be helpful for identification ...